# What is the benefit of setting minmum approval status at publication target

Tags: workflow, bundles

If i set minimum approval status at publication target level. Does it applies to all the item into that publication or only the items in Workflow or Bundle.

For Bundle there will be two cases for items only in a bundle:

1. Workflow has *not* started yet on the Bundle
2. Workflow has been started on bundle

What happens to the flag minimum approval status in above two cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As of Tridion 2013 SP1 minimal approval status will be applied to all items, no matter if they are in workflow or not. Keep in mind that it will not be applied to items without any approval status at all (unassigned).

In previous versions, approval status will only be applied to items in workflow.

So pre 2013 SP1:

1. Approval Status ignored
2. Approval Status applied (if publishing workflow version of an item)

2013 SP1:

1. Approval Status applied
2. Approval Status applied

You can also configure 2013 SP1 to behave like previous versions

Comment: If approval status is applied to all items , how can i publish the items which are not part of any workflow. The items which are part of workflow will get this status as these items progresses in workflow steps.  What happens to the items which are not part of any workflow.

Comment: As the answer states, minimal approval status is not enforced on items without any approval status at all (unassigned), thus if some items are not configured to go through any workflow then they will automatically get unassigned status and can be published.