# Page doesn't get published through bundle in workflow

Tags: workflow, 2013

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1.I have a Bundle X which has workflow associated with it.In one of the workflow steps i am setting the minimum approval status of the bundle and bundle items. The minimum approval status has been set for the publication target.I have added one page into this Bundle.This page has five CP on it. I have started the workflow on this bundle and i am trying to publish this page through code. It gives me an error saying

**Item tcm:26-2152 does not meet the minimum approval status**

This item is not in bundle . This is the component present on the page. So basically what happens is when i publish the page ,all CP on the page also tries to get published. But only page is in bundle so minimum approval status of page is set, minimum approval status is not set for CP on page. how to handle this situation. How can i set minimum approval status of all CP on page when only page is in Bundle.

The code using to publish is as below

```
        VirtualFolderData workFlowBundle = (VirtualFolderData)CoreServiceClient.Read(ActivityInstance.WorkItems[0].Subject.IdRef, new ReadOptions());

        PublishInstructionData publishInstruction = new PublishInstructionData
        {
            ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData()
            {
                IncludeChildPublications = false,
                IncludeWorkflow = true
            },
            RenderInstruction = new RenderInstructionData()
        };

        publishItem.Publish(CoreServiceClient, publishInstruction, new String[] { workFlowBundle.Id }, new String[] { previewTarget }, PublishPriority.High);


        ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData()
        {
            Message = "Email Notification Sent",

        };
```

When i add only component in bundle and start workflow it gets published nicely with code. As all component achieves minimum approval status in one of the workflow steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this first: [What is the benefit of setting minmum approval status at publication target](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/what-is-the-benefit-of-setting-minmum-approval-status-at-publication-target/5364#5364)

So your component was in workflow and has some approval status, other than Unassigned. It means that approval status rules will be applied to it. Even without any workflow, you will not be able to publish it, unless the approval status rule is met, or you disable the check.

Comment: U didn't get my question. I am saying when i add only component in my Bundle and start workflow,it achieves minimum approval status and get published nicely. But once i add page into bundle, it fails as for page minimum approval status is set not for CP on the page.When i try to publish the page through code ,it tries to publish CP on page as well which doesn't have minimum approval set.

Comment: In order to publish anything your item should have approval status higher than that of publication target or be unassigned (not unapproved). If you component has neither - you will not be able to publish it.

Comment: when an item will get status unapproved? i don't know how half of my items have status unapproved.

Comment: When item is created (without workflow) it has approval status unassigned - you can publish it. If it ever was in workflow it gets Unapproved, or approval status set by last activity instance in workflow - min approval status rule is applied

Comment: Yes,I can see this in my components, How can i make it unassigned or what happens when it get approved in workflow. After workflow completion Status is changed to approved or unassigned?  now what will be the status after completion if i publish this to live.What will be next status.

Comment: You can't make it unassigned. You can create a dummy workflow with 1 activity which will set status to whatever you like, or disable this check altogether

Comment: when item is created without workflow it has a status unassigned. Can i make it unapproved somehow while saving.

Comment: Unapproved = item was in WF, Unassigned = item never was in WF. You can make unapproved, but not unassigned

Comment: can i make unapproved on component save?

Comment: you can't, there's no way to do it

Comment: how can i avoid unassigned content to get published to live? as unassigned content can be published directly to live/preview .

Comment: You need to pass it through workflow. The idea is that if there was no workflow at the time of creation it means that content ready to go without approval, otherwise there should've been WF